# Unix path-searching C function

Tags: c, unix, path

I am programming a UNIX shell and I have to use the `execv()` system call to create a process.
One of the parameters for `execv()` is the filepath for the executable.  So if somebody types in `/bin/ls`, it will run the `ls` executable.  But what I need is a function such that when `ls` is typed, it will search for the filepath of `ls` (like the `which` command).  Is there a function which allows me to do that?

Unfortunately, this is a school project and I am not allowed to use `execvp()`. I need to implement some path searching function and then add that filepath to the `execv()` parameter.

Answer (score 13):

Use `PATH = getenv("PATH")` to get the path string from the environment, then use successive calls to `strtok(PATH,":")` then `strtok(NULL,":")` to parse out the paths from the `PATH` string into an array of `char **path`, which you will need to allocate with `malloc()`. Place `path[x]` + `'/'` + `argv[0]` into a buffer, and use `access(buffer, X_OK)` to see if you can execute your file at that path location, if so, perform your `execv(buffer,argv)`.

Comment: Note that you need to make a copy of the string returned by `getenv("PATH")` as otherwise, you are modifying the environment as you use `strtok()`.  That's usually not a good idea!

Answer (score 3):

I think execvp() does what you need.

**Edit:** So you're actually asking how to do this manually? In that case...

1. Find your PATH in envp (3rd argument to main())
2. Split this into individual paths
3. Check for your program's existance in each of these with stat()
4. Execute the first one you find to exist

Or if you want a *really* solid implementation, use [this](http://cvsweb.netbsd.org/bsdweb.cgi/src/lib/libc/gen/execvp.c?rev=1.24&content-type=text/x-cvsweb-markup). It might set off the plagarism detectors though :)

Comment: Using getenv("PATH") is as reliable as using envp; you have to have control of main() to be able to get at that.

Answer (score 3):

You want execvp(), it will search the path specified in the PATH variable unless the filename contains a '/'.

Comment: For thoses not happy with the given excecvp solution, I answered this question in this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14571215/search-for-a-file-in-path-on-linux-in-c/62285620#62285620

Answer (score 3):

If you can't use execvp, you could get the PATH variable from `char** environ` from <unistd.h> or `char* getenv(const char* name)` from <stdlib.h> then use `int access(const char* filename, int mode)` to see if the file exists and is executable.
I'll leave the implementation up to you as it's a school project.

Comment: Using access() isn't entirely reliable; it is best to try 'exec' on the file.  There are a variety of issues with access() - some related to SUID binaries.  Using access() will tell you if the file exists, but so will a failed execv().

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I'm doing the same project now and we got around that problem by using X_OK.

Answer (score 2):

Use `execvp`.

```
char *args[] = {"ls", (char *) NULL};
execvp("ls", args);
```

e.g. this example will exec `/bin/echo` (assuming `/bin` is on your PATH).

```
#include <unistd.h>

int main()
{
    char *args[] = {"echo", "hello world", (char *) NULL};
    execvp("echo", args);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: He can't use `execvp()` just `execve()`

Answer (score 2):

A few people have suggested that you call `access()` or `stat()` before attempting to execute the program with `execv()`. You don't need to do this. `execv()` will return an error if it could not execute the requested file.

Comment: True.  And you might need to distinguish between ENOENT (file does not exist) and ENOEXEC (file is not an executable) to decide whether it is worth trying to execute the 'program' via the shell as a script.

Comment: Not really. If the file exists but is not executable then you can't run it anyway (unless as an arg to /bin/sh - but now you're guessing that it's a script). If it is a script (shell or otherwise) with the proper "shebang" at the top then it will execute as expected.

Comment: @mhawke: While I agree that your opinion is objectively better and more in touch with what users of modern unices expect, strictly speaking POSIX does not honor the "shebang" trick and expects non-binary files to be executed by invoking the standard shell interpreter. `execvp` is actually specified to behave this way if the underlying `execve` would return an `ENOEXEC` error.

Answer (score 0):

`execvp` :-)

Edit: Okay. Here's a Perl version, which can serve as pseudocode for your problem.

```
use List::Util qw(first);

my @path = split /:/, $ENV{PATH};
my $dir = first {$_ ||= '.'; -x "$_/$name"} @path
    or die "Can't find program $name\n";
exec "$dir/$name", @args;
```

`split` splits a string into an array of strings, using the given separator. `first` finds the first item that matches some criterion; here, that the concatenation of the directory and the name being sought after is executable (`-x`). It then runs that.

Hope it helps!

Comment: One nasty trick not accounted for when I typed this - an empty field in PATH needs to be treated like a dot (current directory).

Answer (score 0):

From the execvp man page:

```
   The  functions  execlp() and execvp() will duplicate the actions of the
   shell in searching for an executable file  if  the  specified  filename
   does  not  contain  a slash (/) character.  The search path is the path
   specified in the environment by the PATH variable.   If  this  variable
   isn’t specified, the default path ‘‘:/bin:/usr/bin’’ is used.  In addi-
   tion, certain errors are treated specially.
```

Perhaps you are allowed to use execlp()? If you must use execv you'll need to get the value of the PATH environment variable, parse this using strtok() to get the individual paths, append your filename to each path and attempt to execute it with execv().

I'd provide code, but I'm not doing your homework for you.

Answer (score 0):

Oh a school project...

Well if you want something "like which" why not  just exec "which" itself (/usr/bin/which on linux, not the bash alias or tcsh builtin) to get the path to what you are looking for...

:-)